# Remove product from cart rest API

Tags: magento2

How can I remove product from cart REST API. I searched on

```
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html
```

and could not find any help from above reference.

Answer (score 7):

There is one API under [quoteCartItemRepositoryV1](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html)

```
DELETE /V1/carts/mine/items/{itemId}
```

Comment: anyway we can pass multiple itemIds in this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API call to remove products from cart.

You have to implement it.

See `\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Delete::execute` for a code example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I implement. Please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a nice tutorial for you. Which explains about how to create a custom REST APIs for Magento 2.x. It has all the detailed process. [Please check this.](https://www.thirdandgrove.com/creating-custom-rest-api-magento2)

If you have any doubts please reach me out via comments.

Comment: Like the updateCart() function in the example try to create for deleteCart() function.

Comment: Hi @Asheem Patro

Comment: I wants to remove an item from after order placed.

Comment: Is there any way to remove an item after place order in magento2

Answer (score 0):

The docs are very unclear on how this works.
Here is how i did it.

```
<?php
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
  $quoteId = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuoteId();
?>

<script>window.quoteId = <?= $quoteId ?></script>


<script>
$('.thing').on('click', function (){
  $.ajax({
     url: '/rest/V1/carts/' + window.quoteId + '/items/' + $(this).attr('data-productid'),
     type: 'DELETE',
     headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer <AUTH_TOKEN>"},
     success: function(result) {console.log('Done')}
  });
})
</script>
```